# Determining units of SHAPE_Length and SHAPE_Area fields and reducing/rounding those values?

Tags: arcgis-desktop

[image]

When I run the INVEST SDR I got an error as "**Possibly due to too larger number with respect to field width**" that causes by these large integers of the shapefile area data that is shown as below in attribute table, does anyone knows a solution for this and how to know the units of these data

[image]

Comment: The units are the same as the coordinate system the features are in, from the looks it's either feet or metres, I would ignore shape_leng as it's an artifact and not likely to be correct; that said though I would only trust shape_length and shape_area if the feature class is a geodatabase feature class and not a shapefile export.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For geodatabases, those fields are generated automatically and the values are also maintained automatically and dynamically.  The units are in 'map units'.  Map units are based on the coordinate system.  So to find out the map units, right-click on the layer and choose 'Properties', then look at the 'Source' tab.  Scroll down to view the coordinate system information, and amongst that, look for the 'Linear Unit:' item.

If the Linear Unit was metres (as usual for UTM coordinate systems), for example, the area would then be in square metres.

If you want to get rounded versions of the values or to get the values in some specific units, you would have to create a new field (as type DOUBLE) and then calculate the values.  You could use either the 'Field Calculator' to get the values, but even better is the 'Calculate Geometry' option:

Right click on the field header of a field (of type DOUBLE) in the attribute table, then select "Calculate Geometry".  In the dialogue that appears, you can choose which units you want to use (eg, hectares, kilometres, etc).

Note that whether you use the Field Calculator or the Calculate Geometry option to get these values, they will NOT be maintained automatically by the system, unlike the existing geodatabase fields you circled in your question.  Therefore if shapes change, you will need to re-run your calculations to get updated values.

(As noted by @Michael_Stimson, those SHAPE_Length/SHAPE_Area fields may not be reliable if they are in a Shapefile or non-geodatabase source or if they are not the versions of those fields being produced by ArcGIS for the geodatabase, as they were probably exported/copied, and the values may no longer be correct if the underlying shapes have changed.)

Comment: Thank you so much for your answers! Problem solved! :)